# Proving colinearity of 3 points(basic Euclidean geometry)

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

In the above image,  AP is bisector of the angle BAC and DP is a perpendicular bisector of the segment BC.

How can it be proved that the points E, D, F are colinear?

Comment: You cannot in general ! because it is true only for some special position of $BC$

Comment: What special position? This is an exercise problem in "Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry" and there is no such mention

Comment: And... I solve it actually using Menelaus' theorem!

Comment: Can you add your solution (as an answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $P$ is the mid-point of the minor arc BC of the circumcircle ABC.  So EDF is the [Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line) of the point $P$.

Comment: So, how is the Simpson "line" a line?

Comment: The linked wiki article has a proof, as does many other sites such as [cut-the-knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Simpson.shtml).  I don't think I should regurgitate it here.